# Check for lines in txt file starting with particular word and count the occurences

Tags: vba, excel, count

I've been trying to check if a given txt file has lines that start with a particular word. I then want to count the number of lines that start with that word. Though I can't quite get it right, I do think I'm somewhat close with the check. Any and all help are much appreciated!
Here's my code so far

```
.Pattern = "(\nC_PIN\s)(\b\d\b\s)"
.Global = True
Set objFil3 = objFSO.OpenTextFile(inFileName)
If objFil3.IsMatch(inFileName) Then
 MsgBox "File OK"

Else: MsgBox "Wrong file type chosen. Please check directory"
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robert, use the `.ReadLine` method on your object variable.

```
Dim numLines as Long: numLInes = 0
Dim strSearch as string '## the value you're searching for
strSearch = "Steve!"    '## MOdify as needed
Do While Not objfil3.AtEndofStream
    If Left(objfil3.ReadLine, Len(strSearch)) = strSearch Then
        numLines = numLines + 1
    Else:

    End If
Loop
    MsgBox objFil3 & " contains " & numLines & " beginning with " & strSearch
```

Comment: I get an Expceted End Of Statement error for  `Do While Not objfil3 At EOF`

Comment: Try revised method, above. I'm doing this from memory so let me know if that didn't work.

Comment: No errors from that revision but I'll be doing the testing tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Excellent. The `ReadLine` method reads each line of the stream. I've doublechecked that this is the correct syntax for that method.